# Under what circumstances does bitcoin-qt ban a peer?

Tags: bitcoin-core, peers, banscore

### Under What Circumstances Will Bitcoin-qt Ban A Peer?

In my bitcoin-qt wallet, I am noticing that often there are a lot of banned peers.

Sometimes I have as many as 10 peers banned within the wallet, but I am doubtful that all of these peers are acting maliciously.

I'm curious, what are the circumstances under which the QT wallet will ban a peer?

[image]